# redirect to a page and show popup in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a search bar in my website, but if the searched word is not valid than I do an if statement to redirect user to home page:

```cs
if (jsonResponse is null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I would like that my site redirect to home page after this check on my controller and than show a pop-up in home page saying "You searched for an invalid word"

Comment: you can search for "TempData"

Comment: if you are on the server side...you gotta render a page FIRST that displays the dialog (in javascript) and do the redirect (also in javascript)...the server side doesnt have access to the client and cannot just display a popup on its own...you gotta change the mindset on this a bit

Comment: you can create one extra view page , that will display pop up , using javascript and when user will click on OK button in POP up it will redirect back to  (index , home )

Comment: Would you kindly share your client side core so that I can write a solution for you. Cannot visualize what's actually there.

Comment: Hello is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron how I can accept the answer? I don't know how to do that

Comment: You can do that by right clicking on left check mark beside your question.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron done

Comment: Its my pleasure @lucaspompeun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way,

**Search Page Controller**

```
public IActionResult SearchPage()
        {

           var data =  TempData["serachResultFromDb"];
            if (data != null)
            {
                ViewData["serachResultFromDb"] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PrinterJob>>(TempData["serachResultFromDb"].ToString());
            }
            
            return View();
        }
```

**Search Page Chtml**

```cs
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
@using msPartnerSupport.Models
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Search Page";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchKey", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <table class="table-bordered ">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Search</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="searchkey" placeholder="Enter Search Key" />

                </td>
                <td>

                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
}

<table class="table-bordered ">
    <tr>
        <th>Printer Name </th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    @{

        var searkeyResult = (List<PrinterJob>)ViewData["serachResultFromDb"];
        if (searkeyResult != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in searkeyResult)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td><strong> @item.PrinterName</strong></td>
                    <td><strong> @item.TotalPrint</strong></td>
                </tr>

            }
        }

    }

</table>
```

**Output should be like :**

[image]

**SearchKey Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SearchKey(string searchkey)
    {

        //Searching From Database
        List<PrinterJob> serachingFromDb = _context.PrinterJobs.Where(skey => skey.PrinterName == searchkey).ToList();

        //If no search Result then redirecting to new page
        if (serachingFromDb.Count == 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About");
        }
        //On successful search result 
        TempData["serachResultFromDb"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serachingFromDb);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

> **Note:** I am testing on `Home` controller so directly redirecting to `Index` action. This controller has no view page.

**Index Controller**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "You searched for an invalid word";

            return View();
        }
```

> **Note:** It will be redirected when there will be no search result.

**Index Chtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="samplePopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"> </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @ViewData["Message"]
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function () {
                    $('#samplePopup').modal('show');
                });
            });
</script>
```

**Pop Up When No Search Results:**

[image]

Hope it will help you. Let me know if you have any more concern.